# How do I create a global keyboard shortcut to create a new note in Notes.app or Reminders.app?

Tags: macos, reminders, notes.app

The new Notes app is great but How do I create a new note without switching to the Notes app first?

Same goes for Reminders.app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reminders

You can create a service using the **Automator**:

1. Open **Automator.app**
2. Select **Service**
3. *For Reminders:* Add action **Ask for Text** to prompt for a new To Do
4. Add action **New Reminders Item**
5. Save Service
6. Create Shortcut in:

   *System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Services → Text*

[image]

### Notes

See Mohamad Elwan's answer for notes

Comment: Does this still work for you ?

Answer (score 4):

For **Notes**,

Launch *Automator* --> *Service*

Add the action "*Run AppleScript*"

Replace `(* Your script goes here *)` with:

```
tell application "Notes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Notes" of ((process "Notes")'s (menu bar 1)'s ¬
        (menu bar item "Window")'s (menu "Window"))
    click menu item "New Note" of ((process "Notes")'s (menu bar 1)'s ¬
        (menu bar item "File")'s (menu "File"))
end tell
```

This will work regardless if the Notes app is minimized or hidden.

Then, follow the above procedure to create the global shortcut.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It works great! Bear in mind that the menu items must be localized according to the language of your system, i.e., replace `"Window"`, `"New Note"`, and `"File"` by the corresponding names in your language. I didn't need to change `"System Events"` and `"Notes"` (my system is in French).

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Notes"
        click menu item "New note" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1         
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: It would be useful if *explain* what the script is doing.  It helps people learn/understand how these things work.

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS 12 Monterey, there is a default shortcut for creating a Quick Note from anywhere: <kbd>Fn Q</kbd>.

You can change this shortcut in System Settings. (in macOS Ventura and up, the setting is in *System Settings* > *Keyboard* > *Keyboard Shortcuts…* > *Mission Control* > *Quick Note*).